# Get element from Org through the custom component

Tags: lightning

I'm trying to build custom component to get user's activity into the Org. Component is added into Utility Bar.

For example, here's the code to get the Org's URL after redirect.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!c.onRedirect}"/> 

</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({
    onRedirect: function (component, helper) {
        console.log(window.location.href);
    }  
})
```

How can I get element (button or li) from Org after clicking on it?

I'm using default Org tabs (Reports for example), and I had a custom component in my Utility Bar to tracking user's activity. And I need to track when a user pushes "New Report" button.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get the element that triggered the event (and it's attributes):

```
<a href="#" onclick="{!c.handleEvent}">trigger event</a>

handleEvent: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var url = evt.target.href;
},
```

Be sure you also passed the event `function(cmp, evt, helper)` because you are not doing that right now.

In case you triggered the event with a lightning component like a `ui:button`, you would use the `getSource()` method, to get your button component:

```
var buttonCmp = evt.getSource();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I need to get an element from standart Salesforce tab and I cant use onclick action.

Comment: But this is what you said "How can I get element (button or li) from Org after clicking on it?" Not sure if I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Basti, thanks for your help. Please check the screenshot to clarify my question.